# How to sniff cdp message-packets from a cisco switch using JAVA

Tags: java, cisco, packet-sniffers, raw-ethernet

I am trying to sniff a cdp packets from a cisco switch.

**Because I am going to deal with a lot of switches I can't specify all models,** I am asking in general is there a way to this using java?

Comment: Java isn't well suited for such low level work. You'd have to use native code/libraries.

Answer (score 1):

CDP is a proprietary protocol by Cisco **at the MAC (Ethernet) layer**, it is not based on TCP/IP. So, the `java.net` Java API can not handle CDP frames.

So, you MUST use a third party library based on JNI native calls to access the underlying networking system interface. **Typically, a PCAP Java wrapper will do the job**. You could try [JNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/), that should work on Linux and Windows. You can download it here: http://jnetpcap.com/download